# This Browser does not support ServiceWorkers message

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I implemented a manifest.json and a serviceworker.js in an existing little vuejs project. I would like to add the app to the android homescreen. But on all plattforms, chrome70/windows or android chrome I get "This Browser does not support ServiceWorkers"

why?

the json:

```
{
  "short_name": "dsdfsdf",
  "name": "Fsdfsdfdf",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon-48.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon-96.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "start_url": "index.html"
}
```

the app.js looks:

```
'use strict'

+function() {
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
        alert('This Browser does not support ServiceWorkers.')
        return
    }

    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        console.info('ServiceWorker runs')
        return
    }

    console.info('Registering ServiceWorker ...')
    navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('./serviceworker.js')
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error('ServiceWorker has not been registered!', err)
    })
}()

if (location.search)
    if (location.search.slice(1) === 'from_hs')
        document.querySelector('h1').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<h2>Hey, I\'m an app!</h2>')
```

Comment: Your IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) has a typo. Change it to this:
```(function(){

})();``` Also make sure you add semicolons in your code before a new line

Comment: Also make sure you serve your files through an ssl connection, see the [criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria)